# Cabling between inverter and single board computer

Tags: networking, cable, rs232, cabling

I'd like to interface an inverter with Gateworks [GW5220](http://www.gateworks.com/imx6-single-board-computers-gateworks-ventana-family/item/ventana-gw5220-single-board-computer). The inverter has an RS232 port shown below and GW5220 has a 5-pin RS232 Serial interface. The GW5220 serial connector is labeled as follows:

- Pin 1: GND
- Pin 2: RX1/CTS
- Pin 3: TX1/RTS
- Pin 4: RX2
- Pin 5: TX2

I'm making a cable that runs between the GW5220 and the inverter. I have a CAT6 cable with a [T-568B](https://www.showmecables.com/blog/post/rj45-pinout/) RJ45 jack at one end that connects to the inverter. At the other end are exposed wires which will connect to their corresponding pins on the GW5220. The problem is I don't know what signals go with what wire on the CAT6 cable. 
Can someone help assign the the GW5220 pins to their colored wire on the CAT6?
Inverter RS232 Connection: [image: Inverter RS232 Connection]

GW5220 RS232 Connection:
[image: GW5220 RS232 Connection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a specific pinout not mentioned in your inverter's manual, then RS-232 serial over an RJ-45 (8P8C) connector frequently uses the [rollover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_cable) format, also called [Yost cable](http://yost.com/computers/RJ45-serial/) or [Cisco console cable](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/7000-series-routers/12223-14.html#topic15).

The RJ-45 pinouts for this type of cable (table copied from the previous Yost.com link) are:

```
                              PINS
FUNCTION                    DTE  DCE
------------------------    ---  ---
CTS (clear to send)          1    8
CD (carrier detect)          2    7
RX (receive data)            3    6
GND (receive ground)         4    5
GND (transmit ground)        5    4
TX (transmit data)           6    3
DTR (data terminal ready)    7    2
RTS (request to send)        8    1
```

The inverter is most likely a 'DCE' device (as it isn't a computer/terminal).

I'm not sure why the GW5220 has two sets of RX/TX pins; maybe that's for an alternate mode (RS-485 serial)? I assume the pins function as GND/CTS/RTS/RX/TX when in RS-232 mode.

(Note: RS-232 doesn't usually use a twisted-pair cable, but if that's what you have, the Yost.com article recommends rewiring it to pair **3-4** and **5-6**, instead of the typical Ethernet 3-6 and 4-5.)